# Calling private function from inside another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, structure, private, public

I'm having trouble getting my head around calling an internal function from inside another. I need to be able to call funcA on page load passing it an element and some dimensions which then applies some styles to the passes elem. funcB then uses said parameters to size the element correctly:

```
var funcA = function(elem, width, height) {

     //performs layout restyle
     function funcB() {
          //performs sizing 
     }

     funcB();
}
```

However, the issue is I need to recall funcB from within a debounced resize function like so.

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};
var resizeFn = debounce(function() {

    funcB();

}, 10);

$(window).on('resize', resizeFn);
```

What's the best practice for making funcB available? I'd been considering returning it and then caching it to variable:

```
var funcA = function(elem, width, height) {

     //performs layout restyle
     function funcB() {
          //performs sizing 
     }

     funcB();

     return funcB
}

var scopedFuncB = funcA;

scopedFuncB();
```

But is there a better way?

Comment: How and where do you define the debounced resize function?

Comment: returning it to form a closures sounds like a viable way. What don't you like about it? Please show us the whole code of that attempt.

Comment: See above, it's not that I don't like it, it's viable, just wondering if there's a way of doing it without polluting the global namespace

Comment: If its an internal function should you really be calling it externally? and if so why not make it an external function?

Comment: I think you will want `var scopedFuncB = funcA(…);` (and maybe not even call `funcB()` from within `funcA`).

Answer (score 1):

> I'd been considering returning it

Yes, that's definitely best practise. So the caller can decide what do with it and when and how often to call it.

> …and then caching it to variable

No need for that actually. You can directly pass it to `debounce` without further ado:

```
$(window).on('resize', debounce(funcA(elem, width, height), 10));
```

Comment: This is a good solution. jQuery should be added to the question as a tag.

Comment: @Grimbode: Well, the answer would be the same if `window.addEventListener('resize', …, false)` would have been used, so not jQuery-specific enough to need a tag for it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make funcA return something and then funcB does its stuff receiving that funcA's output as a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options:

```
var funcA = function(elem, width, height) {
    if(!(this instanceof funcA)){
         return new funcA(elem, width, height);   
    }
     //performs layout restyle
     this.funcB = function() {
          //performs sizing 
     }
}

funcA(elem, width, height).funcB();
```

or

```
var funcA = function(elem, width, height) {
     //performs layout restyle
     var funcB = function() {
          //performs sizing 
     }
     window.funcB = funcB;

}

funcA(elem, width, height);
funcB();
```